# Create UILocalNotification not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Below is my method to create UILocalNotification:-

```
-(void)addNewNotification{
    //snooze for 1 minute
    NSMutableDictionary *myUserInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [myUserInfo setObject:@"Snooze reminder" forKey:@"infoID"];
    //1 for Meds
    //2 for Cream
    [myUserInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"MedType"];
    [myUserInfo setObject:self.reminderTimeString forKey:@"ReminderTime"];

    NSString *alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cream time at %@",self.reminderTimeString];
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
    localNotification.userInfo = myUserInfo;
    localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2*60];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
}
```

I have printed out the firedate and its exactly what I want. But the problem is that, the notification is not firing up when the time is up. 
Am I adding the local notification correctly ?

Comment: please comment this line `localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];` and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not register local notifications? Does your app request permission to use notifications?

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

Comment: i did and it was because of the timezone issue. all i had to do was just removing the timezone